# Program started using Run() is unable to locate its config file

Tags: windows, autoit

If I run `c:\myfile.exe` from cmd prompt it works and loads its config file properly. But the same thing using AutoIt has the program start, but then ignores its config file:

```
Run("c:\myfile.exe")
```

Why doesn't it run correctly like it does from cmd prompt ?

Comment: Without knowing what "myfile.exe" does it's impossible to tell. Look for logs, some output or other traces of its activity. As a blind guess, look for startup directory differences.

Comment: myfile.exe is a monero miner. I try to build an autoit script wich will restart my miner depnding of my computer activity (idle or not). If I launch myminer from cmd, it works and load the configfile.txt, but the if I do exact same thing with autoit (Run....), my miner open but without the config file loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Helpfile shows](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm):

> Run ( "program" [, "workingdir" [, show_flag [, opt_flag]]] )

Set the "workingdir" (path to the config file). Your "program" searches in the working directory for its config file. It defaults to the AutoIt script's working directory, which equals `@ScriptDir`.

Following your example, it should be:

```
Run("C:\myfile.exe", "C:\")
```

Answer (score 0):

does running it from cmd, rather than executing it directly, result in the expected behavior?

```
Run("cmd /c c:\myfile.exe")
```

or

```
Run(@ComSpec &  " /c c:\myfile.exe")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It doesn't works, conf file still ignored.